# Angular material 1 / md-virtual-repeat select scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scroll, scrollbar, angular-material

What is the right way to change md-virtual-repeat's scroll to watch events from an other scroll ?

I have tried some manual triggering

And i readed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41175828/md-virtual-repeater-using-body-as-container) but it is not exactly i want.

So is there a way to select a scrool to virtual-repeat container ?

**EDIT 2**

I need to change scrollbar of virtual repeat with scrollbar of **Body**

Live example

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

  app.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(text) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
  }]);

  app.controller('AppCtrl', function($timeout) {
    this.itemSize = 529.39;

    var DynamicItems = function() {
      this.loadedPages = {};
      this.numItems = 0;
      this.PAGE_SIZE = 50;
      this.fetchNumItems_();
    };

    DynamicItems.prototype.getItemAtIndex = function(index) {
      var pageNumber = Math.floor(index / this.PAGE_SIZE);
      var page = this.loadedPages[pageNumber];

      if (page) {
        return page[index % this.PAGE_SIZE];
      } else if (page !== null) {
        this.fetchPage_(pageNumber);
      }
    };

    DynamicItems.prototype.getLength = function() {
      return this.numItems;
    };

    DynamicItems.prototype.fetchPage_ = function(pageNumber) {
      this.loadedPages[pageNumber] = null;

      $timeout(angular.noop, 300).then(angular.bind(this, function() {
        this.loadedPages[pageNumber] = [];
        var pageOffset = pageNumber * this.PAGE_SIZE;
        //console.log(pageNumber);

        for (var i = pageOffset; i < pageOffset + this.PAGE_SIZE; i++) {
          var obj = {};
          obj.name = 'Ad ' + i;
          obj.surname = 'Soyad ' + i;
          obj.age = i;
          obj.image = 'http://lorempixel.com/75/75/cats?' + i;
          obj.list = [];
          obj.clicked = false;
          obj.status = "asd";
          obj.html = '' + i + '---Lorem Ipsum, dizgi ve baskı endüstrisinde kullanılan mıgır metinlerdir. Lorem Ipsum, adı bilinmeyen bir matbaacının bir hurufat numune kitabı oluşturmak üzere bir yazı galerisini alarak karıştırdığı 1500 lerden beri endüstri standardı sahte metinler olarak kullanılmıştır. Beşyüz yıl boyunca varlığını sürdürmekle kalmamış, aynı zamanda pek değişmeden elektronik dizgiye de sıçramıştır. 1960 larda Lorem Ipsum pasajları da içeren Letraset yapraklarının yayınlanması ile ve yakın zamanda Aldus PageMaker gibi Lorem Ipsum sürümleri içeren masaüstü yayıncılık yazılımları ile popüler olmuştur.' + i;
          for (var j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            obj.list.push('http://lorempixel.com/75/75/city/?' + j);
          }

          this.loadedPages[pageNumber].push(obj);
        }

        //this.setItemNum(this.numItems + this.PAGE_SIZE);
      }));
    };

    DynamicItems.prototype.fetchNumItems_ = function() {
      $timeout(angular.noop, 300).then(angular.bind(this, function() {
        //console.log("fetchNumItems_");
        this.numItems = 10000;
      }));
    };

    DynamicItems.prototype.setItemNum = function(number) {
      this.numItems = number;
    };

    this.dynamicItems = new DynamicItems();
    //console.log(this.dynamicItems);
  });
}());
```

```css
.virtualRepeatdemoDeferredLoading #vertical-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.virtualRepeatdemoDeferredLoading .repeated-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.virtualRepeatdemoDeferredLoading md-content {
  margin: 16px;
}
.virtualRepeatdemoDeferredLoading md-virtual-repeat-container {
  border: solid 1px grey;
}
.virtualRepeatdemoDeferredLoading .md-virtual-repeat-container .md-virtual-repeat-offsetter div {
  padding-left: 16px;
}
.virtualRepeatdemoHorizontalUsage #horizontal-container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.virtualRepeatdemoHorizontalUsage .repeated-item {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 84px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
.virtualRepeatdemoHorizontalUsage md-content {
  margin: 16px;
}
.virtualRepeatdemoHorizontalUsage md-virtual-repeat-container {
  border: solid 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html class=''>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/favicon-8ea04875e70c4b0bb41da869e81236e54394d63638a1ef12fa558a4a835f1164.ico" />
  <link rel="mask-icon" type="" href="//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/favicon/logo-pin-f2d2b6d2c61838f7e76325261b7195c27224080bc099486ddd6dccb469b8e8e6.svg" color="#111" />
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWXMXW" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.1/angular-material.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/docs.css'>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js'></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.1/angular-material.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1> Virtual Repeat Test </h1>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl" ng-cloak="" flex layout-fill layout-padding class="virtualRepeatdemoDeferredLoading" ng-app="MyApp">

    <md-content layout="column" flex layout-fill>

      <md-virtual-repeat-container flex layout-fill md-auto-shrink="false" layout id="vertical-container">

        <div md-virtual-repeat="item in ctrl.dynamicItems" id="repeat_item" md-on-demand="true" md-item-size="ctrl.itemSize" layout-fill>

          <img ng-src="{{item.image}}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{item.name}}" />
          <br> Adı : {{item.name}} <br> Soyadı : {{item.surname}} <br> Yaşı : {{item.age}} <br> is Clicked : {{ item.clicked }} <br> status : {{ item.status }}
          <p ng-bind-html=" item.html | to_trusted "> </p>

          <h5 ng-click="item.clicked = !item.clicked; item.status = item.status + item.status; "> List Items </h5>

          <md-content ng-if="item.clicked == true" class="virtualRepeatdemoHorizontalUsage" layout="column">

            <md-virtual-repeat-container id="horizontal-container" md-orient-horizontal="">
              <div md-virtual-repeat="picture in item.list" class="repeated-item" flex="">
                <img ng-src="{{ picture }}" class="md-avatar" alt="{{ picture }}" />
              </div>
            </md-virtual-repeat-container>
          </md-content>

          <br>

        </div>

      </md-virtual-repeat-container>
    </md-content>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Regarding your edit, is the `md-virtual-repeat` going to take up the whole area in the window? If so, would it be easier to just hide the body scrollbar and use `md-virtual-repeat` scrollbar as the "official" scrollbar?

Comment: No because there would be multiple virtual-repeat on page at the same time.

Comment: I see, in that case I'd use the updated directive in my answer, but I'd still use a separate div that stretches the height of the window as the scrollbar and disable the body scrollbar so that your `md-virtual-repeat` tags aren't inside the thing that you're scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to scroll the virtual repeater div using a scrollbar somewhere else on your page? One way to do that would be to create a directive that listens to scroll event of the div you want to use as the visible scrollbar and then just scroll the other div the same percentage.

Here is one such directive. Add it to the md-virtual-repeat-container and point it to the div you want to scroll it. The divs can even be different heights.

**Update**
I changed the directive to fall back to the body tag if an element wasn't specified.

```js
app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) {
    $scope.items.push(i);
  }
});

app.directive("scrollFrom", function($window, $document) {
  return {
    scope: {
      elTarget: '@scrollFrom'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var body = $document[0].body;
      angular.element(scope.elTarget || $window).bind("scroll", function() {
        var percentScrolled = scope.elTarget ?
          this.scrollHeight > 0 ? this.scrollTop / (this.scrollHeight - element.height()) : 0 :
          body.scrollHeight > 0 ? body.scrollTop / (body.scrollHeight - element.height()) : 0;
        var trgt = angular.element(element).find('.md-virtual-repeat-scroller')[0];
        trgt.scrollTop = trgt.scrollHeight * percentScrolled;
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
#vertical-container {
  height: 292px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
}

#vertical-container .md-virtual-repeat-scroller {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.repeated-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 40px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

md-virtual-repeat-container {
  border: solid 4px grey;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="height: 5000000px">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container" scroll-from>
      <div md-virtual-repeat="item in items" class="repeated-item" flex>
        {{item}}
      </div>
    </md-virtual-repeat-container>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer can solve this problem but i need a scrollFrom directive not scroll for. And somehow with your way scrollFor directive cant see virtualRepeats scroll. I tried to target all containers even containers after dom render but it not worked for me..

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız, please see my updated answer that uses an `md-virtual-repeat` and changes the directive to a `scrollFrom` as requested.

Comment: I tried your directive but it not worked for document's scroll. I fixed it but the problem i got is now the height of scroll. Document has so small scroll and virtual-repeat has 5000000 or bigger height. I think a watcher scroll is not the solve. I need to change the virtual-repeat's scroll to document's scroll orginally

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız, sorry, I don't understand. It's not working because the document is so small so you want to change it to use the document's scrollbar? If the document is too small, how would changing it to use the document's scrollbar help?

Comment: Document has 1000 scrollHeight virtual-repeat-container has 5000000 scrollHeight so when i scroll on document virtual-repeat scrolls so much because your directive works with percent naturally. I need same scroll height (by the way it is out of the scope of my question)

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız, please see my new update. I changed it to scroll from the body. If the document height of the body is too small so it scrolls your virtual repeats too fast, simply set the height of the document to something larger.

Comment: @BurakAkyıldız, I added one more update where I changed the example to have 5,000,000 items and I changed the height of the body to be large enough so that a single click on the scrollbar would only scroll the `md-virtual-repeat` a little way so you wouldn't skip items.

Comment: Thank you so much for your work. If i cant find a way to change scrollBar of virtual-repeat-container with an other item i will give you the bounty but your answer is not true solve i will not accept it.